# Using an explicit UID/GID in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, containers

The best practices page mentions the below:
(https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#user)

```
Consider an explicit UID/GID
Users and groups in an image are assigned a non-deterministic UID/GID in that the “next” UID/GID is assigned regardless of image rebuilds. So, if it’s critical, you should assign an explicit UID/GID."
```

What is the significance of explicitly specifying the UID/GID?
Under what scenario allowing the system to assign the UID/GID does not provide sufficient security?

Explicitly specifying these values seem to have the downside of a leading to a situation in which the explicitly specified value (UID/GID) is already in use.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more significant for the case where someone might be dependent on the specific numeric uid, maybe to inject data into a container.

```sh
# this needs to be readable by the container process
# it runs as non-root user "www-data"
# we think its uid is 18
sudo chown -R 18 data
sudo docker run -v ./data:/data -p 8888:80 imagename
```

Now if, due to changes in the base image outside either the image author's or end user's control, `adduser` makes the uid be something else, recipes like this will break (the host has no direct way to see the container's `/etc/passwd` file to know what the actual uid will be).

To work around *that* you maybe need a recipe like this:

```sh
# may or may not work to get the uid
CONTAINER_UID=$(sudo docker run --rm imagename id -u)
sudo chown -R "$CONTAINER_UID" data
```